# Wordpress contact form (404 not found)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I created a template on WordPress and I made an html form. It works well in HTML but doesn't work when used on WordPress. It seems that it doesn't find my `contact-send.php` page and it displays a 404 Error page.

My permalinks were on default and it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
If any of my code is needed, I'll post it. I just didn't because I think it's not a code error once it doesn't find `contact-send.php`.

Comment: could you provide that site url once

Comment: please give me site url so we can check that actuall problem

Comment: Check path for that `contact-send.php` through the **Inspect Element**

Comment: create a page that uses contact-send.php as its template.

Comment: can you tell me the attribute name of text field in your contact for, remember do not use reserved keyword in attribute name of text filed like name etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an absolute URL for the target of your form instead of just `action="contact-send.php"`.

But unless you have particularly unusual requirements for your contact form, you will likely have better results using one of the many popular contact form plugins like [**Contact Form 7**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/).

Using a well-maintained plugin ensures stability, and more importantly, security. Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you, I used the Contact Form 7 instead. I really wanted to use my contact form but it's not working, so I used this one. Btw, do you know how can I edit the styles of this contact form?

Comment: I found it, thanks.
[Contact Form 7 Style](http://contactform7.com/styling-contact-form/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/contact-send.php`.  When you write **contact-send.php** only then it don't find your file which is in your theme.  So use this `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/contact-send.php` in form action. This change may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be caused due to 3 reasons.

1. Giving wrong path in action tag. Using `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/contact-send.php` will solve this problem.
2. Missing `contact-send.php` page in the themes folder. This problem can be solve by adding the page to the themes folder.
3. Improper `.htaccess` file. This can be solved by recreating the code for your .htaccess file from `Dashboard` > `Permalinks` and paste it in the `.htaccess` file in the WordPress root directory.

I am giving the explanation in the assumption that your template file is directly in the themes folder.

Comment: I changed my .htaccess code. Can this be the problem?
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: No, I mean, I had that code on .htaccess. I meant if that could be the problem. Although I changed to a plugin from wordpress for my contact form. Thank you.